# Plugin SWAP vector direction doesn't work in QGIS

Tags: qgis-plugins, vector, editing, qgis-2

I've installed plugin Swap vector direction in QGIS.
But it doesn't work. I click and nothing.
I need to flip lines (22 000 000 lines).

In ArcGIS takes many hours and still flipping.
I thought maybe in QGIS will be faster, but doesn't work.

Why doesn't this plugin open?
Maybe is another way to flip lines in QGIS?
I know there is solution in GRASS, but GRASS doesn't open so big file.
Version QGIS 2.4.0 Chugiak

Comment: I installed the plugin into QGIS 2.6.0 and I agree that it does not seem to do anything. I believe that myself I would have a try with SpatiaLite and Reverse https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html. Something like `UPDATE lines SET geometry=ST_Reverse(geometry)` or perhaps with a safer way by creating a new table as `create table reversed_lines as select id, ST_Reverse(geometry) from lines` If you have PostGIS installed the same SQL should work.

Answer (score 1):

I used the Swap Vector Direction plugin to reverse direction on a single polyline. Select layer and toggle editing on before pressing the Swap Vector Direction button.
 I use the Line Offset plugin to create offsets 10 ft. left & right of road centerline. The left offset line is in same direction as centerline but the right offset is reverse. Applying the Swap Vector Direction tool to the right offset resolved my linear reference issue.